# ListTile OnTap is working when I use ListView. But when i use ListWheelScrollView it doesnt work

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

ListTile OnTap is working when I use ListView. But when i use ListWheelScrollView it doesn't work. I mean it doesn't get tapped. The view changes. But i can't seem to tap it. I looked for the solution in a lot of places and links but still couldn't find the solutions.

These are the code I did.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListWheelScrollView(
      physics:FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
      children: getPostList(),
      itemExtent: 100.0,
    );
  }

  List<PostListItem> getPostList() {
    return _postModal
        .map((contact) => new PostListItem(contact))
        .toList();
  }
```

And this is where I have built the ListTile

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListTile(
      onTap:  () {
          var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                new OnTapPost(value: _postModal.fullName),
          );
          Navigator.of(context).push(route);
        },
        leading: new Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
        title: new Text(_postModal.fullName),
        subtitle: new Text(_postModal.email)
    );

  }
```

In the above code the list items doesn't get tapped. But if i replace the ListWheelScrollView with ListView as shown below, it works perfectly.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListView(
      children: getPostList(),
    );
  }

  List<PostListItem> getPostList() {
    return _postModal
        .map((contact) => new PostListItem(contact))
        .toList();
  }
```

Comment: This might be an issue, you'll just have to use a different kind of list for now. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38803

Comment: At last the solution was released i guess. Its in the link https://pub.dev/packages/clickable_list_wheel_view

Answer (score 1):

Update: Another look no update yet from the flutter team but another hack solution. By wrapping the whole listscrollwheel widget with a Gesturedetector. Every scroll sets the state using the "onSelectedItemChanged" for listscrollview. But the gesture detector widget does something with it only on tap.

```
  import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   
    
    class ServicesList extends StatefulWidget {
    
      final type;
    
      ServicesList({this.type});
    
      @override
      _ServicesListState createState() => _ServicesListState();
    }
    
    class _ServicesListState extends State<ServicesList> {
    
      double _height ,_width;
      int serviceIndex;
      final FixedExtentScrollController _controller = FixedExtentScrollController();

 

List<Service> serviceList = [
    Service(name: 'service 1'),
    Service(name: 'service 4'),
    Service(name: 'service 3'),

];
    
      @override
      void initState() {
    
        serviceIndex = 0;
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
      }
    
      detectService(index) {
        print('clicked container : $index'); //do whatever you want with the clicked index
      }
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
               
        return scrollWheel();
      }
    
    
    
      Widget scrollWheel() {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            detectService(serviceIndex);
            },
          child: ListWheelScrollView(
            controller: _controller,
            diameterRatio: 1.5,
            itemExtent: 80,
            onSelectedItemChanged: (e)=>{
    
              setState(() {
                serviceIndex = e;
              })
            },
            magnification: 0.2,
            physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
            children: serviceList.map((e) {
    
    
                return Container(
                  padding:  const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  child:Text('item $e.name');
                );
          }).toList(), //List of widgets
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  
   class Service {
      String name;
 
     Service( {this.name} );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

after two to three years, and a big discussion in the link provided by @TWL too (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38803) the issue seems to be resolved by a wrapper for ListWheelScrollView that allows children to respond on the onTap events.
https://pub.dev/packages/clickable_list_wheel_view

Although I am now not in need of this solution after these few years, I hope it helps others who wants to solve this issue.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue
If you still want to use a ListWheelScrollView and not a ListView in your case,

You can wrap the ListWheelScrollView inside a GestureDetector, and make a List of your _postModals.
use the onSelectedItemChanged to determine which list item index that is currently selected , then create a global Index variable. Here is an example of what I mean :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListScrollWheelExample extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

List<PostModal> _postModals = [
  //Add your postModals here
];
int Index;

return GestureDetector(
  onTap: (){
    var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) =>
      new OnTapPost(value: _postModals[Index].fullName),
    );
    Navigator.of(context).push(route);
  },
  child: ListWheelScrollView(
    onSelectedItemChanged: (int index){
      Index = index;
    },
    offAxisFraction: -0.85,
    diameterRatio: 0.75,
    physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
    itemExtent: 100,
    children: <Widget>[

      getPostList(),

    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

and in your ListTile :

```
leading: new Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
title: new Text(_postModals[Index].fullName),
subtitle: new Text(_postModals[Index].email)
```

I used this way because I still like the wheel appearance and I don't want to convert to a ListView, but try not to make the diameter of the ListWheelScrollView so large to keep the tapping functionality work as expected.

Edit :
If you want multiple items to be clickable (the 3 or 4 visible items), you can wrap the ListWheelScrollView in a stack with 3 or 4 Gesture detectors. Then use Index-1 and Index+1 , ...etc

Comment: This does not address the issue. The question is asking about tapping on any item in the list, not just the one that is selected at the center of the ListWheelScrollView,

Comment: @BrysonThill My answer addresses the issue, because in our case, we use FixedExtentScrollPhysics() which its usage will be mostly for clicking the current item in the ScrolWheel ,and again it is not a ListView, not all items appear on front.