# Flutter: InkWell completely non-functional in Card

Tags: flutter, material-design

Pasted below is the build method for a widget based on Card that serves as a list element in a ListWheelScrollView. The TweenAnimationBuilder is simply to animate a background color change in the Card widget whenever it's the currently selected list item.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Color primary = Theme
    .of(context)
    .primaryColor;
Color secondary = Colors.white;

return new TweenAnimationBuilder(
    tween: new ColorTween(
        begin: secondary, end: selected ? primary : secondary),
    duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    builder: (BuildContext context, Color color, Widget child) {
      return new Card(
          color: color,
          child: new InkWell(
              splashColor: Colors.blue,
              child: new Container(
                  height: 75,
                  width: 400,
                  child: new Center(
                      child: new Text(quiz.title)
                  )
              ),
              onTap: () => print("Does nothing")
          )
      );
    }
);}
```

No matter what I do, there are no visual splashes on the Card nor does the onTap handler ever execute.
I've tried every solution I've seen here on SO. Really confused on this one.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I don't know how you're doing it, try this code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var primary = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
  var secondary = Colors.white;
  var selected = true;
  return Scaffold(
    body: TweenAnimationBuilder(
      tween: ColorTween(begin: secondary, end: selected ? primary : secondary),
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Color color, Widget child) {
        return Card(
          color: color,
          child: InkWell(
            splashColor: Colors.blue,
            onTap: () => print('Does nothing'),
            child: Container(
              height: 75,
              width: 400,
              child: Center(child: Text('Title')),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Wrapping the TweenAnimationBuilder in a Scaffold did nothing. The parent tree looks like this: SafeArea > Scaffold > Column > Expanded > Container > ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate > QuizCard. The above method is the build method for QuizCard. Further details if they're helpful: ListWheelScrollView delegate is ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate and ScrollController is FixedExtentScrollController.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately after getting a little more creative with my search queries, I discovered the answer is that this is simply how Flutter works. Children of a ListWheelScrollView cannot receive gesture input. I suppose this shouldn't be that surprising given how the widget is intended to function. To save others the frustration, please see the duplicate SO question and discussion on Google's Flutter Github linked below. Also linked is a Pub workaround package found via the Flutter Github discussion I'm looking into now.

[ListTile OnTap is working when I use ListView. But when i use ListWheelScrollView it doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56255739/listtile-ontap-is-working-when-i-use-listview-but-when-i-use-listwheelscrollvie)

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38803

https://pub.dev/packages/clickable_list_wheel_view